# Frequency of a regex pattern at each position of sublist

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary

I have a list of lists:

```
x = [[AATG, ATAT, GGCC],
     [CCTA, TCGT, AAAA],
     [TTAA, GGAT, TACA]]
```

The character inside the lists are the combinations of ATCG only and each element in list of lists has length of four characters. The inner list has equal length.

I want to estimate the frequency of an elements which has only all combinations of A and T; for example ATAT (first row second column), AAAA (second row third column) and TTAA (third row first column) in each column.

For calling all combination of A and T I have used regular expression:

```
 pattern = re.findall('[AT]{4}', key)
```

For reading list of lists

```
y = []
for i in range(len(x[0])):
    per.append(len([j[i] for j in x if j[i]==pattern])/len(x))
print(y)
```

This code is working if I use a particular string like 'ATAT':

```
y = []
for i in range(len(x[0])):
    per.append(len([j[i] for j in x if j[i]=='ATAT'])/len(x))
print(y)
```

but it doesn't work for pattern with regrex. The could be anything which can called by re.findall, for example:

```
'[CG]{4}' for all element has C or G
'^(?=[GC]*[AT][GC]*$).{4}$' for 75% of element has G or C
```

The expected output:

```
[0.34, 0.34, 0.34]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your if statement `if j[i]==pattern` you check if `j[i]` is equal to the result of [findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) which return all non overlapping matches.

You could use `if pattern.match(j[i])` [re.match](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) instead as you want to check if the match is 4 times matching what is in the character class.

```
x = [['AATG', 'ATAT', 'GGCC'],
     ['CCTA', 'TCGT', 'AAAA'],
     ['TTAA', 'GGAT', 'TACA']]

pattern = re.compile('[AT]{4}')

y = []
for i in range(len(x[0])):
    y.append(len([j[i] for j in x if pattern.match(j[i])])/len(x))
print(y)
```

Result:

```
[0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333]
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/KU0nzr)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a membership check without regex to make this a simpler check: just check if the element is made up entirely of 'A' and 'T'.

```
x = [['AATG', 'ATAT', 'GGCC'],
     ['CCTA', 'TCGT', 'AAAA'],
     ['TTAA', 'GGAT', 'TACA']]

members = {'A', 'T'}
result = []
for row in x:
    #creates a list of bools, True only if an element contains just items from members set
    element_status = [all(char in members for char in element) for element in row]
    result.append(sum(element_status)/len(element_status))

print(result)
[0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333]
```

To do the same with the regex, your pattern does work. You just have to use the length of elements returned if you use findall.

```
import re
x = [['AATG', 'ATAT', 'GGCC'],
     ['CCTA', 'TCGT', 'AAAA'],
     ['TTAA', 'GGAT', 'TACA']]

members = {'A', 'T'}
pattern = '[AT]{4}'
result = []
for row in x:
    element_status = [len(re.findall(pattern, element)) for element in row]
    result.append(sum(element_status)/len(element_status))

print(result)
```